# 1 row matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, determinant

In [Line-plane intersection in parametric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection#Parametric_form) article determinant of matrix is used to check whether solution exists. Matrix elements are vectors. I don't understand how determinant is found and why it results in dot product of first element with cross product of 2 other elements. As far as I concerned, we can calculate determinant for square matrix only. I appreciate any feedback. Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Maybe they join many vectors to create a square matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that at the very start of the article, the vectors $\mathbf{1}_a$ and $\mathbf{1}_b$ are defined in the form $\mathbf{1}_j:=(x_j,y_j,z_j)\in\mathbb R^3$. So, these are really points in space. when taking the determinant $$\det(\begin{bmatrix}
-\mathbf{1}_{ab} & \mathbf{p}_{01} & \mathbf{p}_{02}
\end{bmatrix})\,,$$ we ought to interpret the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
-\mathbf{1}_{ab} & \mathbf{p}_{01} & \mathbf{p}_{02}
\end{bmatrix}$ as a "block" matrix with three entries, each of which is a $3\times 1$ column-matrix. Thus, in this convention, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
-\mathbf{1}_{ab} & \mathbf{p}_{01} & \mathbf{p}_{02}
\end{bmatrix}$ is really a $3\times3$ square matrix as desired. This is why the determinant of such a matrix makes sense.

The fact that $$ \det(\begin{bmatrix}
-\mathbf{1}_{ab} & \mathbf{p}_{01} & \mathbf{p}_{02}
\end{bmatrix}) = -\mathbf{1}_{ab}\cdot(\mathbf{p}_{01}\times\mathbf{p}_{02}) $$ is really an application of the definition of a $3\times 3$ determinant. You should check this result by expanding along the **first column** of $\begin{bmatrix}
-\mathbf{1}_{ab} & \mathbf{p}_{01} & \mathbf{p}_{02}
\end{bmatrix}$, which in this case is $-\mathbf{1}_{ab}$. Can you check this by yourself ?

Comment: Thank you a lot. It was not clear for me that 1x3 matrix of vectors is in fact a 3x3 matrix. Now everything is clear for me.

Comment: @KirillDolghi : I am glad to be of help :)